# How do I run my lambda for a specific amount of time and then exit gracefully?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

As aws lambda has max timeout of 15 minutes, I want to run my lambda 14.5 minutes and then exit out gracefully before the 15 minutes are up. The lambda uses aws sqs sdk to poll for messages using ReceiveMessages.

How can I do this?

I have tried using setTimeout so that after the timeout I can gracefully exit from the lambda, like so:

```
const handler = async(event, context) => {
  const timer = setTimeout(() => {
    // exit from here
  }, context.getRemainingTimeInMillis() - 30000 * 1000); // 14.5 min timeout
  try {
    // call sdk.receiveMessages() and process further
  } finally {
    clearTimeout(timer);
  }
}
```

Can this be done easier via step function?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have to ask for the use case here? Why do you want to keep paying for lambda execution if your lambda has finished its work?

Comment: @AnthonyB. So the lambda will use sqs sdk's receiveMessages to fetch messages from a queue (20 is the max limit) and process them. Since there will be a lot of messages in the queue the lambda will reach the timeout of 15 minutes before processing all of them.
What I'm thinking of doing is, process the items till the 14.5th minute and then exit gracefully and call the same lambda again to process the remaining items from the queue.

Comment: How do you trigger the lambda? Don’t you use sqs as a source trigger for your lambda in batch mode (either time window or size)?

Comment: Why not trigger the processing every time a new item is put into the queue? You are basically using a serveless service (Lambda), like a server.

Comment: Why aren't you using Lambda's SQS integration? As pointed out by other comments here, you are basically reinventing Lambda's SQS integration, in a way that is more expensive.

Comment: Set the lambda timeout to max 15 minutes. Then have while loop with context context.getRemainingTimeInMillis() >  30000. You will need to call the sdk.receiveMessages inside it and process it. Its bit procedural code but I have seen it working flawlessly. Probably use the SQS trigger to do the process increase the concurrency.

Answer (score 0):

based on your comments, it seems like you are not using lambda the right way.
If you have items in a SQS queue that needs to be processed, then you can use [Lambda to process messages from the queue in batch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html#events-sqs-eventsource). I'd suggest to chose a right batch value, so that your lambda will not timeout. Since you already mentioned about 20, then you can maybe start with a batch size of 20.

**How does it work?**

AWS Lambda will be triggered once the number of visible items in the SQS queue reaches 20. While the lambda is processing those 20 messages, if another batch of 20 messages is ready to be processed, then another lambda will be trigger.

There is a [tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs-example.html) on AWS documentation to understand a bit more the SQS integration with lambda.